# MySQL Workbench doesn't SAVE EER diagram

Tags: mysql, diagram, workbench

I have been using WB for quite a long time, the diagram feature is definitely one of the features I love most, in one of my projects over 50 tables have been nicely layout in the diagram, when I got my 4x4 A4 pages of diagram printed I really feel good!

However today when I accidentally closed the 'EER Diagram' tab I realised I lost all of my diagram?!!! I cannot see anywhere to open the closed diagram, is it just gone?!!!

Even though I have my source version control saved most of my previous works it would only take me couple of minutes to add back what I have modified, I found it really strange that WB doesn't have a save/open button for the diagram.

I tried googling it but didn't find any posts mentioning the similar issue, am I missing something from the software interface? Or am I the only one used the feature so much and suddenly lost the work?!!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Wokbench each diagram belongs to a model (the model is in a separate tab) so it will let you close your diagrams without asking you to save your model. It does ask you to save your model when you try to close an opened model with unsaved changes.

So, in short, if you are not being asked to save a model once you try to close it with unsaved changes, then that's a bug you should report in http://bugs.mysql.com. Otherwise you can recover your diagram by opening its parent model and double clicking on the diagram's icon in that model.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes, some of the documents mentioned I should be able to 'click the diagram icon' in the model, however I cannot see that button from my latest copy of WB, any ideas?

[screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/jq0s9i/6)

Comment: It might be that you didn't save the model. In that case there won't be any diagram to open.

Comment: I have been using the model file for almost 2 years, it's saved very often and I have it in my source version control. You might want to see the [http://tinypic.com/r/jq0s9i/6](screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/jq0s9i/6) of my WB. Is it different from what you have on your screen?

Comment: Yes, mine is like this: http://i48.tinypic.com/nwl9nr.png. What WB version are you using?

Comment: Looks I just found another bug of the WB!! I created a new model file and can see the EER Diagram section now, but can't see that with my existing file. Time to file the bug again.... I'm using the latest one available by the way :)